# jackson:Issue with bean class having multiple setters with same name and different type paramas

Tags: java, json, jackson

json simply giving `mapperException` Conflicting setter definitions for property

```
public void setJanuary(String january) {
    try {
        setJanuary(Float.parseFloat(january));
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        setJanuary(0);
    }
}public void setJanuary(float january) {
    this.january = january;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you expect? Support both string and number ?

Comment: yes @AlexeyGavrilov. Those i have already used in my Java App..now i am using same bean classes for mobile app with Json

Answer (score 8):

Problem resolved by using Annotation **@JsonSetter** for which setter we are using from Json

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the setter methods that should be excluded.

Comment: Thanks...i tried By using '@JsonIgnore' annotation it simply ignoring getter method too...

Comment: @phani just put the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the getter.